# How to include a variable in ngModel

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Because I am using `ngInclude` to switch different templates, each template contains the same form to call the same functions in the controller. I want to include a defined variable, like a table name, to the `ngModel`, so I can use it to filter the data in either js code or PHP code, in order to insert the information into the right table.

I did some researches but did not find any. Does anyone knows how to do it, or have better idea how to do it?

Thank you

Comment: `ng-model` are used for `input` type tags. You can simply use `ng-model="myModel"` if you are using it with input tag. But if you want to bind some variable with other tags then i suggest use of custom directives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry it is a stupid question and I just solve it, I added a value into the parameter of the submit function, like `ng-click="submit(file, 'poster')"`, then use it to deal with the js code and php code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular `ui-router` instead `ngInclude` for loading html template, then you can pass data as variable

take a look at this 
https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/